# sequelize .create is not a function error

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting `Unhandled rejection TypeError: feed.create is not a function` error and I can't understand why it occurs. What's the problem here?

Here's my code. I'm probably not doing something very fundamental here since I can't reach feed variable in routes/index.js.

If I add module.exports = feed; to my models file, I can reach it, but I have more than one models, so if I add additional models below the feed, they override it.

db.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('mydatabase', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 8889,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    },
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

var db = {};
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

models.js

```
var db = require('./db'),
    sequelize = db.sequelize,
    Sequelize = db.Sequelize;

var feed = sequelize.define('feeds', {
    subscriber_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    activity_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
{
    tableName: 'feeds',
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var models = require('../models');

router.get('/addfeed', function(req,res) {
    sequelize.sync().then(function () {
        return feed.create({
            subscriber_id: 5008,
            activity_id : 116
        });
    }).then(function (jane) {
        res.sendStatus(jane);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot reach a variable from a file, by only requiring it in another one. You need to either define an object literal to hold all your variables in one place and assign it to `module.exports`, or you need to import them from different files separately.

In your case, I would create separate files to hold table schemas, and then import them by `sequelize.import` under one file, then require that file.

Like this:

models/index.js:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('DBNAME', 'root', 'root', { 
  host: "localhost",           
  dialect: 'sqlite',           

  pool:{
    max: 5, 
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000                
  },

  storage: "SOME_DB_PATH"
}); 

// load models                 
var models = [                 
  'Users',            
];
models.forEach(function(model) {
  module.exports[model] = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
});
```

models/Users.js

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports=function(sequelize, DataTypes){ 
  return Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
      field: "id",             
      autoIncrement: !0,       
      primaryKey: !0
    },
    firstName: {               
      type: DataTypes.STRING,  
      field: "first_name"      
    },
    lastName: {                
      type: DataTypes.STRING,  
      field: "last_name"       
    },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    classMethods:{

      }
    },
    instanceMethods:{

      }
    }
  });
};
```

Then import each model like this:

`var Users = require("MODELS_FOLDER_PATH").Users;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed this i am getting error `Cannot read property 'all' of undefined`

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```js
const { User } = require("../models");
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update :**

**in newer version of sequelize `v6` and beyond `sequelize.import` is deprecated**

[sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) recommend using require now

### If you have generated models using migrations

this is how your model file will look like

*models/user.js*

```
'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes, Model) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
        }
    };
    User.init({
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20)
        },
        otp: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(4).UNSIGNED
        },{
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
    });
    return User;
};
```

as you can see your model export function has `sequelize` `DataTypes` & `Model` parameters.

**so when you import this model you should send above arguments.**

#### Example

I am importing user model in *controllers/user.js* file, it could be any file

*controllers/controller.js*

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db').sequelize;

// Bring in Model
const User = require('../models/user')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes,
     Sequelize.Model);
// your code...
// User.create(), User.find() whatever
```

Notice that `sequelize`(with small 's') and `Sequelize`(with capital 'S') **are different** things, first one represent instance of Sequelize created using new Sequelize, second one is just package you installed & imported

first one (`sequelize`) can be found wherever you started a connection to database using `const sequelize = new Sequelize()` usually from app.js or db.js file, make sure to export it from there and import it into where you want to use Model i.e controller

*export sequelize instance*

*db.js* Or *app.js*

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize();
... //your code
...
module.exports = {
sequelize: sequelize
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came with the same issue when I used something like:

```
const { Feed } = require("../models/Feed.js");
```

So, just using the code down below solved it

```
const { Feed } = require("../models");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the answer given on the link below tackling the same issue, I was able to resolve mine using `const User = sequelize.import('../models/users');`, instead of just `import User from '../models/users';`

[Sequelize create not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875714/sequelize-create-not-a-function)