# Sequelize create not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, koa

I am trying to use model.create and it's saying that model.create is not a function. I googled around and couldn't seem to find any rmesolutions. Please note that I'm using es6 imports / exports in node via babel.

model.js

```
'use strict';
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  let attachments = sequelize.define('attachments', {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    category: DataTypes.STRING,
    value: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  attachments.associate = (models) => {
  };
  return attachments;
};
```

controller

```
import attachments from '../../../models/attachments'
import to_attachments from '../../../models/to_attachments'
import AWSService from '../../utils/awsS3Api'

export async function createPhoto(ctx) {

 ... 

  try {
      let attachment = await attachments.create({
        type: 'image',
        category: imageCategory,
        value: data.location
      });
..etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare model via function:

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  ...
};
```

Then you should import it with `sequelize.import`

```
const Attachment = sequelize.import('../../../models/attachments')

export async function createPhoto(ctx) {
  const attachment = await Attachment.create({
    type: 'image',
    category: imageCategory,
    value: data.location
  });
}
```

**P.S. Some recommendations**

1) Name model variables with capital letter you deal with static classes.

```
const user = await User.findById(123)
const users = await User.findAll({where: {id: [1,2,3]}})
```

2) Singular not `Users` but `User`.