# Sequelize: create is not a function when model is generated from migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I created this model from sequelize CLI

**models/society.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Society = sequelize.define('Society', {
    code: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Society.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Society;
};
```

Then this is my **index.js** file for configurations

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const api = require('./routes')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', api)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`API REST running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

The part of routes is this

**routes/index.js**

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const api = express.Router()

const SocietyCtrl = require('../controllers/society')
api.post('/society', SocietyCtrl.createSociety)

module.exports = api
```

And finally it's just the controller
**controllers/society.js**

```
'use strict'

const Society = require('../models/society')

function createSociety(req, res){
    console.log('POST /api/society/')
    Society.create(req.body).then(created =>{
        res.status(200).send({society: created})
    })
}

module.exports = {
    createSociety
}
```

The problem comes when I try to make POST, I get this following error:

*Society.create is not a function*

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried Society.Society.create() ?

Comment: You can use `console.log(Society.create)` to check what it is. Make sure your models are organized correctly.

Comment: Because **models/society.js** return a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequelize .create is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313569/sequelize-create-is-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Amjed! 
But I didn't need to add index.js to `models` directory because sequelize already did.
However all I needed to do was:

```
'use strict'

const db = require('../models/index')
const Society = db.Society
```

And then it worked like it was supposed to.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is not related to migration, however to solve this problem you have to do two steps:

**1)** Add new file in `models` directory called `index.js` which contain the following code

> **NOTE:** make sure to edit sequelize config (with your environment) which starts in line `9` and ends in line `13` in file below (`models/index.js`)

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);

const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3066,
  dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
});

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
  const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

**2)** in `controllers/society.js` file do the following

- replace `const Society = require('../models/society');` with `const db = require('../models/index');` or `const db = require('../models');`
- replace `Society.create` with `db.Society.create`

like this:

```
'use strict'

const db = require('../models');

function createSociety(req, res){
    console.log('POST /api/society/');
    db.Society.create(req.body).then(created =>{
        res.status(200).send({society: created})
    });
}

module.exports = {
    createSociety
}
```

---

To learn more I recommend you to check a github repository called [express-example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) which developed by official [sequelize team](https://github.com/sequelize)